# Spring model to JsonObject conversion failing due to circular reference

Tags: java, spring, jackson

**Controller**

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth")
public class OAuthController {

    @Autowired
    private OAuthService oAuthService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/authorization-url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Response getAuthorizationUrl() {
        try {
            TempOAuthToken tempOAuthToken = oAuthService.getTemporaryOAuthToken();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(tempOAuthToken.toJsonObject()).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JsonObject errResponse = new JsonObject();
            errResponse.addProperty("error", e.getMessage());
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(errResponse).build();
        }
    }

}
```

**TempOAuthToken.java**

```
public class TempOAuthToken {

    private String requestToken;
    private String tokenSecret;
    private String authorizationUrl;
    private String verificationSecret;

    public JsonObject toJsonObject() {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("requestToken", this.requestToken);
        json.addProperty("tokenSecret", this.tokenSecret);
        json.addProperty("authorizationUrl", this.authorizationUrl);
        return json;
    }
}
```

I used `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` as return type. So, that I can return JsonObject with anything in it. I wrote `toJsonObject` method to convert `TempOAuthToken` model to JsonObject. I got following error:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Could not write content: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: 
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ResponseImpl["entity"]-com.google.gson.JsonObject["asJsonObject"]); 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
 com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ResponseImpl["entity"]-com.google.gson.JsonObject["asJsonObject"])
```

It seems something is referencing itself creating a cycle. Can someone help me in finding the issue?